# Vue/Nuxt - Getting element by id in client returns null on load but works on reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using [VueScroll](https://vuescrolljs.yvescoding.org/) as a container for a carousel. Unfortunately I noticed that when a user has their mouse on the VueScroll element and wheel-scrolls the elements inside the VueScroll to zoom in/out. I am wanting to get the element and add a listener to handle the wheel scroll event.

To get the element I tried the following:

```
created(){
    if(process.client){
      if(document.getElementById('vueScroller')){
            console.log('vueScroller created');
        } else {
          console.log('fail...') 
        }
    }
  },
```

And I noticed that on the **initial** load I get "fail..." but if I change something in the code and the app **hotreloads** I get "vueScroller created", so I figure I am close but not understanding where I am going wrong and/or why it acts differently depending on what triggers the page to load.

Comment: Use a ref instead of a DOM lookup

Answer (score 3):

If you use `created()` the template has not yet been rendered. Using `beforeMount()` or `mounted()` should fix your problem.

Have a look at the life cycle diagram for reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram